# How to adjust the width of the bars in a pyramid graph using the "age_pyramid" function from the "apyramid" package?

Tags: r

I'm using the R package apyramid to build a pyramid like graph, but I can't find the option to set the width of the bars. The readme notes established that the graph generated is a ggplot2 object so it can be customized like that, but the commands for setting the wide value are not recognized when used.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apyramid/readme/README.html

So, if anyone could help me, I'll be grateful.

I tryed ggplot2 command
geom_col(width = 0.25) but adds another barplot on the original one, overlapping with the correct bars.

I expected to manipulate the wide of bars and maybe the gaps.

Comment: Hi Marco, welcome to SO! It always helps to provide some example data and the code that you have already tried. Those things generally improve the answers you get on SO!

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your feedback, is just I can't publish my data yet, so that's why I use the readme example.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It still helps to provide a minimum working example with simulated or data. Having real data in the structure of your own data makes the solutions you receive much more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `geom_col()`, you are instructing `ggplot2` to add a new column geometry to the existing plot. What you need to do is change the *existing* geometry. You need to edit the existing object created by `age_pyramid()`. The bars are the first layer created by the `age_pyramid()` function, so you can set the width of the bar on that layer (here, `flup` is the plot object created in the example code from which you linked):

```r
flup$layers[[1]]$geom_params$width <- 0.25
```

This is a bit of a hack and, if you eventually want to produce your own population pyramids, you should just create your own `ggplot` function. [Here's a post from R-Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2023/09/creating-population-pyramid-plots-in-r-with-ggplot2/) to get you started.

Comment: Nice!! that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help it was very useful and super fast.